How to create jwt signature for GET request using josekit in Rust?
I am using jwt::encode_with_signer(&payload, &header, &signer) to generate the signature for the POST request, and it is working fine. Now for the GET request, I need to pass empty payload just "". If I pass JwtPayload::new() as payload I am getting {} as payload and I can't pass "" as payload to encode_with_signer function.
How to solve this? I am using josekit and rust.
What are you doing?
I am creating a signature using a private key based on my request header and payload. I want to do this using rust.

If I'm understanding you correctly, then you aren't using JWTs for their intended purpose. A JwtPayload is a "claims" structure for storing auth info in a token. It sounds like you just want to sign the body of a request/response. If so you should be looking at josekit::jws instead. Apologies if I missed the mark.

I'm also confused, can you perhaps provide some code, and clarify what is server and what is client code, and if this is a inter server request or if it is from an untrusted client?

let payload = serde_json::Value::String("".to_string());
let signature = jwt::encode_with_signer(&payload, &header, &signer);

The serde_json::Value enum allows you to represent different JSON values flexibly. The Null or empty object approaches are typically the most standard ways to represent an empty payload in JWT.
